# Integrating an absolute difference transformation

Tags: probability, linear, uniform-distribution

**I have a dependent variable which is $$ W = |X - Y| $$ X and Y are independently distributed where $ X \sim Uniform(0,1)$ and $ Y \sim Uniform(0,2)$
What am I supposed to do is find the probability of $W \le 0.5 $**

I have split the function to two case one being $ X > Y$ and the other $ Y > X $ so I can define two functions for Y one is being $ Y = W + X$ for $Y > X$ and the other being $ Y = X - W$  for $ X > Y$. And then I tried to write down the integrals.

**Trial 1:**

$$\int_0^{0.5} \int_x^{x+w} \int_0^y dx\frac{dy}{2}dw$$ for $Y > X$ and
$$\int_0^{0.5}\int_y^{y+w} \int_0^x \frac{dy}{2}dxdw$$ for $X > Y$

When I evaluate these integrals and sum them, the answer comes out as a function of Y and X since it is far from being definite as I have not been provided with any X or Y values.

**Trial 2:**

Then I thought that maybe I should use $\int_x^{x+0.5}dy$ instead of $\int_0^{0.5}\int_x^{x+w}dydw$ which I still cannot understand why they give different values.

Then my function became

$$\int_x^{x+0.5} \int_0^y dx\frac{dy}{2}$$ for $Y > X$ and
$$\int_y^{y+0.5} \int_0^x \frac{dy}{2}dx$$ for $X > Y$

which led me to oppose the same problem now I cannot think of an alternative solution to this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It might help to recognize that the transformation $(X,Y)\to|X-Y|$ is not linear.  It almost always helps to draw a diagram of the region(s) of integration.

Comment: The triple integrals are not valid, as $W$ is a deterministic function of $X$ and $Y$. The triplet $(X,Y,W)$ thus does not have a density (in the standard sense).

Answer (score 2):

Comment. Maybe some simulation results (from R) will help you get a mental picture of this problem.

```
set.seed(213)
X = runif(10^6);  Y = runif(10^6, 0,2)
W = abs(X-Y)
mean(W <= .5)
[1] 0.437011    # aprx 7/16 = 0.4375


hist(W, br=20, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
 abline(v=.5, col="orange", lwd=3, lty="dotted")
```

[image]

*Using fewer points for better plots of individual points.*
Points plotted in orange, are the ones that match $\{W < .5\}.$
(Integration is probably best done in two pieces. However, because the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is uniform, you could get
the answer by geometry instead of integration.)

```
x = X[1:n]; y = Y[1:n];  w = W[1:n]
plot(x, y, pch=".")
 points(x[w<.5], y[w<.5], pch=".", col="orange")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hi: I won't do all the work so this is not a complete answer but take the first case where W = (Y - X) > 0.

Then, if W < 0.5, then that means that Y  < 0.5 + X.

So, the double integral goes from 0 to 1 on X and from 0 to 0.5 + X
on Y.  So, one gets

$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{0.5 + x} \frac{1}{2} ~dy~dx $

The other case is similar except that (X - Y) > 0.

Answer (score -1):

I have just solved the question so, here is the answer, **I am changing the question as find the probability of W≤0.6 because I think that value serves better for purposes of teaching and will eliminate any possible confusions in the question.**

First of all what we should do first is to assign probabilities.

If $ W = |X-Y|$ and $Pr(W <= 0.6)$ we are looking for $ Pr( Y - X <= 0.6)$ for $ Y > X$. $Y\epsilon[X,X+0.6]$

We are looking is in my domain as well as all $X\epsilon[0,1]$ So my integral for $Y > X$ is:

$$Pr(Y - X <= 0.6|Y>x) = \int_0^1 \int_x^{x+0.6}\frac{dy}{2}dx = \frac{3}{10} $$

and ${Pr( X - Y <= 0.6)}$, $Y\epsilon[X - 0.6, X]$ for $X\epsilon[0.6,1]$ so integral for $ X > Y$ is:
$$Pr(X - Y <= 0.6|X>y) =\int_{0.6}^1 \int_{x-0.6}^{x}\frac{dy}{2}dx + \int_0^{0.6} \int_0^{x}\frac{dy}{2}dx$$

Now all we have to do is sum that two integrals and then the probability of $ W <= 0.6 $ equals to::

$$ \frac{3}{10}+\frac{6}{50}+\frac{9}{100} = \frac{51}{100}$$

Comment: It's much clearer and complete than my answer. thanks for taking the time to write it out.

Comment: @mlofton since there is somebody who confirmed it, I guess I can mark it as answered. Thank you